# newbie: multi-window (not Document based), is this design sound?

Tags: cocoa

I'm a newbie and wanted to know if I'm on a relatively correct path.

I have a CoreData application, but not Document based (it's not a document but a central DB with many window/view possible).

Two type of window exist (B and T) to view different aspect of the data.

Since it's possible to open many B or T windows simultaneously (to show different part of the same aspect) I decided to create two subclass of NSWindowController (B_Controller, T_Controller) each with his own nib file (B.xib, T.xib).

In my AppDelegate, whenever some menu/shortcut is activated I allocate the corresponding controller, initWithWindowNibName:, show the window and enabled the File->Close menu.

**Questions**:

- Is it correct to have one controller per window ? Or better/possible to have only one controller for all window of the same type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vague newbie question. Maybe this response:

- NSWindowController is for one window only.
- if you want a central place for all window use your AppDelegate.
- if you want a central place for all window of some kind, create new class to do just that.